# Why inner functions are called before outer functions?

Tags: javascript, function

In the code example below the output will be `3 2 1`. Why not `1 2 3`? Doesn't an opening parentheses symbol `(` in `a1(` call indicate that this function must be invoked first? And all stuff inside parentheses, i.e. `a2(a3(50))` must go as a `number` parameter to `function a1` ?

```
function a1(number) {
  console.log("1");
  return number;
}

function a2(number) {
  console.log("2");
  return number;
}

function a3(number) {
  console.log("3");
  return number;
}

a1(a2(a3(50)));
```

Comment: How would JS know what to pass to `a2` before calling `a3`?

Comment: It may know it somehow. JS engine/compiler can be smart.

Comment: @yaru — It might know what value the function will return *before* it runs it? No. JS compilers aren't smart or precognitive, they are just good at following instructions.

Comment: JS is not a lazy-evaluated language.

Comment: I Alice - when you get package shout "One!" and give it to the next person. Bob, when you get a package, shout "Two!" and give it to the next person.  Carol, please shout "Three!" and this to the next person. Now, Alice, stand next to Bob. Bob, stand next to Carol. Carol, here is this package. What would the order of the shouts be?

Comment: @Quentin, so, arguments passed to function must be of type "concrete value"? And if any of parameters represents call to another function - that function must be executed before calling outer function?

Comment: The `type` doesn't matter. Parameters of a function are evaluated before being passed to the functions. If you have `sqrt(log(4))`, which one is executed first? The log or the sqrt?

Comment: @yaru Yes, every expression in JS evaluates to a concrete value, there are no "references" or "[thunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)" that can be passed around. If you want to pass a representation of some code (like a call to another function), you can wrap it into a function and pass that - the function receiving this callback argument can then run it when it wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the `(` in `a1()` means to call it. And the very first thing that it does is to evaluate the parameter that is passed in. In this case a function call is passed in, that is a function with its own set of `()`.

That means that `a1` needs to wait for `a2` to be evaluated so that it can pass in the returned value from calling `a2` into `a1` as a param. The same goes for `a2` accepting `a3` as a parameter.

In the following psuedo code you can see:

```
function a1(number) {
  return number;
}
```

If you call this as such:

```
a1(2+3) // you can't just run a1(2)
```

You have to evaluate `2+3` first, and to evaluate a function called with parenthesis, you have to run the entire function. In your case that function logs something to the console.

Edit: Adding this below because it was in the comments and it the answer that OP was looking for.

The first function call actually starts a new execution context and that function jumps to the top of the 'call stack', but the first thing that function does is evaluate the argument. If that argument is a function, then it kicks off its own execution context and it moves to the top of the 'call stack' and so on. And as stacks work on a 'last in, first out' basis, the most recent one has to be evaluated first.

Comment: In your example `a1(2+3)` why `2 + 3` can not be passed to `a1` as an argument? Why it need to be evaluated first to `5`? Does it have something to do with operators precedence order? But in this table https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table "Addition" is on place 13, but "Function Call" is on position 19 and following that logic "Function call" must happen before an addition, because it has higher precedence.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're thinking, but a function call is after the closing parentheses, not after the opening one. So `a1(5) + 3` would need `a1()` to be called before the addition to `3` - just like the table of order of precedence. But a function needs to evaluate what is between the parentheses before it can be called. What comes between the parens is the first step in calling that function.

Comment: @yaru that is true if you do `a + b()` - in that case `b()` would be evaluated before `a + __result___`. You cannot pass `2+3` as a parameter because it *isn't* - more specifically, it isn't a value. It's an expression that has to be evaluated to *produce* a value. Hence the evaluation before passing it. In the same sense as you can't do `myVar = 2+3` - you write the value you get from the expression to the variable. Otherwise you never really evaluate them.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand function's call logic better. So, function is called NOT when a parser/compiler sees opening parentheses, but when it sees a closing one?

Comment: Yeah, for simplicities sake. Many functions will take, more than one parameter, separated by commas. So the function needs to know what the parameters are before it can do anything. Like `function add(a, b) { return a + b }`, if you called `add(7, 100)` the function would need to wait until the closing paren `)` to know that it needs to add 7 to 100. If it kicked off at the opening `(` it wouldn't yet know what it is trying to add together.

Comment: I say for 'simplicity' because the opening `(` actually starts a new execution context and that function jumps to the top of the 'call stack', but the first thing that function does is evaluate the argument. If that argument is a function, then it kicks off its own execution context and it moves to the top of the 'call stack' and so on. And as stacks work on a 'last in, first out' basis, the most recent one has to be evalutated first.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know (about call stack and execution context). Thanks @BrettEast

Answer (score 5):

The JS engine has to run the function so it can get its return value so it can pass that to the next function.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you have done is you have passed the output of one function as an argument to another function.

In order to pass value returned by a3 it must be executed first. Hence you get 3 2 1 as output.